# Listview causes exception - windows universal app 8.1

Tags: javascript, windows, listview, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I have a list view to choose content from

```
<div id="mediumListIconTextTemplate"
     data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template"
     style="display: none">
    <div class="mediumListIconTextItem">
        <img class="mediumListIconTextItem-Image" src="img/tegan.jpg" />
        <div class="mediumListIconTextItem-Detail">
            <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: title"></h4>
            <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: text"></h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="groupedListView" style="display:none;"
     data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
     data-win-options="{itemDataSource: myData.groupedItemsList.dataSource, tapBehavior: 'toggleSelect',
    itemTemplate: select('#mediumListIconTextTemplate'),
    groupDataSource: myData.groupedItemsList.groups.dataSource,
    groupHeaderTemplate: select('#headerTemplate'),
    layout: {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout}}">
</div>
```

What i did is, i just made listview **'display:none'** and on click add i just made **'display:block'**. The code below

```
  $("#groupedListView").css('display', 'block');
            var name ='';
            var myListView = document.getElementById("groupedListView").winControl;
            myListView.forceLayout();
            myListView.selection.clear();
            myListView.addEventListener("iteminvoked", function (e) {
                e.detail.itemPromise.then(function (invokedItem) {

                   name = invokedItem.data.picture; //name of selected data 
                   alert(name + "\"s defined: " + num + ".", 'i');
                   $("#groupedListView").css('display', 'none'); //hide the listview

                });
            }, false);
```

Its works fine for one time, On 2nd, 3rd... list item selection it fails and shows exception
[image: debugger error]
What is the best way to load listview and access the content..?

P.S: The whole listview and other functions are in single html page

Comment: Quick question--is the "alert" call you're making window.alert? If so, that might be your cause: window.alert is not supplied to Store apps and thus will throw as a non-existent function, Try console.log instead. Also, the stack trace in VS might give you a better idea of where the exception is being thrown that takes you to the debugger, but the alert is the first thing to check.

Comment: @KraigBrockschmidt-MSFT Im alert is the function name i created, it have message.async for displaying....

Comment: I put your template and code like you have above (swapping out the $/.css jQuery stuff for just setting the list's style.display property. Everything works fine multiple times. I can try with jQuery if you tell me the exact version you're using. Also, what does the stack trace in VS say?